# reassign global boolean from a function

Tags: python

i am trying to reassign the value of these booleans from inside of a function and use the reassigned values inside of another function. how do i do that?

```
booleanA = False
booleanB = False

def choose():
    inPut = input("A or B?: ")
    
    if "A" in inPut:
        booleanA = True
    if "B" in inPut:
        booleanB = True

def mainCode():
    
    if booleanA == True:
        #do something
    if booleanB == True:
        #do something else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should avoid trying to do this, as it can make your code harder to understand and debug (see [action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming))).

But, if you're *really* sure you want to do this, you need to use the `global` keyword to tell the interpreter that you're reassigning to the boolean variables defined outside of the function rather than creating fresh variables:

```py
def choose():
    global booleanA
    global booleanB
    inPut = input("A or B?: ")
    
    if "A" in inPut:
        booleanA = True
    if "B" in inPut:
        booleanB = True
```

Comment: hey so i put the global booleans inside of choose() but when i try to access them in mainCode() it says they are not defined

Comment: How are you calling the methods?

Comment: with if statements like if booleanA == True:

Comment: I'm referring to the methods `choose()` and `mainCode()`.

Comment: choose()

mainCode()

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: after all methods and other code there is this at the end of the code: choose() #linebreak maincode()